# Как создать фильтр для ссылок меню WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, вёрстка

При создание меню функцией wp_nav_menu() имеем такие сслыки:

> < a href="...">Пункт меню< /a>

Нужно заменить их на ссылки такого вида:

```
< a href="...">< span data-hover="Пункт меню">Пункт меню< /span>< /a>
```

Подскажите как это сделать правильно фильтром.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения:
В нашей функции добавления меню (wp_nav_menu) есть замечательный атрибут $walker.
По ссылке выше есть пример его использования. Не буду его приводить полностью, лишь необходимый отрывок.

> $item_output = sprintf(
> '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
>         $args->before,
>         $attributes,
>         $args->link_before,
>         apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
>         $args->link_after,
>         $args->after
>     );

Меняем на

> $item_output = sprintf(
> '%1$s<a%2$s><span
> data-hover="%3$s%4$s%5$s">%3$s%4$s%5$s</span></a>%6$s',
>         $args->before,
>         $attributes,
>         $args->link_before,
>         apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
>         $args->link_after,
>         $args->after
>     );

И получаем необходимый результат. Разобравшись что к чему вы можете сделать мелкие изменения для себя ^_^